# Tkinter: Detecting a window drag event

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an animation running in my window, which I would like to pause whenever the user drags the window, to ensure a smooth interaction.

I have tried the following:

```
root.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda e: start_stop_animation(False))
root.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda e: start_stop_animation(False))
root.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda e: start_stop_animation(self._is_running))
```

It seems that these calls do not bind to the title bar at all.

I would like to do this without removing the title bar using `root.overrideredirect(True)`, unless there is a simple way of replacing it with a similar title bar capable of capturing these events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Window dragging is captured by the `<Configure>` event, which is also triggered by window resizing.

To execute different actions at the beginning of the dragging, during the dragging and at end, you can use the `after` method:

Each time a `<Configure>` event happens, you schedule a call to your `stop_drag` function with a given delay, but you cancel this call each time another `<Configure>` event happens before the end of the delay.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

drag_id = ''


def dragging(event):
    global drag_id
    if event.widget is root:  # do nothing if the event is triggered by one of root's children
        if drag_id == '':
            # action on drag start
            print('start drag')
        else:
            # cancel scheduled call to stop_drag
            root.after_cancel(drag_id)
            print('dragging')
        # schedule stop_drag
        drag_id = root.after(100, stop_drag)


def stop_drag():
    global drag_id
    print('stop drag')
    # reset drag_id to be able to detect the start of next dragging
    drag_id = '' 


root.bind('<Configure>', dragging)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Should the second last line not bind to `dragging`?

Comment: You have to be careful here - when you add a binding to `root`, that binding will be triggered for every widget, not just the root widget. For example, if you add a frame that fills the root window, when you resize the window the event will be triggered both for the window and for the frame.

Comment: You have a bug in your code which prevents it from running. You bind to the function `drag`, but there is no function named "drag" (I assume you meant to use `dragging`).

Comment: @BryanOakley @Tjaart, you are right, it's `dragging` not `drag` in the second last line, I've edited my answer to fix that.

Comment: @BryanOakley Is there a way to bind the event to only the root window and not all its children?

Comment: @j_4321 It seems like you could check for `event.widget == root`.

Comment: @Tjaart I have already added this in the answer, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @j_4321: yes, you can create a custom bind tag just for the root window, and then bind to that tag. Or, like Tjaart recommends, just check in the binding for the root window.

Comment: <Configure> only gets bound to resizing in linux not to dragging. How do you do that in linux?

Comment: @Vivek I am using Linux and the `<Configure>` event is triggered by both resizing and dragging when I test it on my computer.

Comment: @Vivek Which linux distribution do you use? I use Archlinux and the code from my answer works. Have you bound `<Configure>` to the root window?  Because when you bind `<Configure>` to a widget (e.g. a frame), then it is triggered only on resizing, not dragging.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found what I was doing wrong.