# Is there a way to create a second window that connects to the parent window like a dropdown menu

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make it so that new information shows in in a new window, but I want the new window to be connected to the parent window, even when the parent window is clicked the new window should still show up similar to how a dropdown menu works. I'm also planning on having some of the new windows have treeviews later on.

```
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()
win.geometry("500x500+0+0")
def button_function ():
    win2 = Toplevel()
    label = Label(win2,text='dropdown', width=7)
    label.pack()
    win2.geometry(f"+{win.winfo_x()}+{win.winfo_y()+30}")
button = Button(win, command=lambda: button_function (), width=12)
button.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: First change `command=lambda: button_function ()` to `command=button_function`. In this case you have no need for a lambda. As for your overall question we will need more context. Are you wanting to be able to move the main window while the drop down window moves with it or do you want the drop down window to lock the main window out and if you move the drop down window then the main window moves with it?

Comment: I want to be able to move the main window and have the rest of the windows move with it.

Comment: That might be hard to accomplish. When you have a "drop down" it stays while it has focus but when you click outside of that focus and force the focus to the main window the drop down should go away on its own. So to accomplish what you want you will probably need to write a custom handler that catches the events involved and keeps the drop down window active. More like a toggle option than a drop down. And you will need to force the drop down window to stay in front. Or make it easier and just manage a frame in the main window that changes when selecting your drop down.

Comment: Toplevel() actually seems to make it so the new window stays on top even when the main menu is clicked. I'm more concerned with trying to make the new windows follow the main window.

Comment: Toplevel() does not force the window to stay on top. It simple builds another window within the same TK instance. You can handle movement easy enough by intercepting the even that manages movement of the main window and then use that to make the toplevel window move at the same rates.

Comment: I did this long ago with C++ and the Windows API, and it was one of the hardest things I've ever done. I think in Python with Tk it will be impossible or close to it.

Comment: @MarkRansom Maybe. I have been able to move all windows in the past by tracking the mouse events and then updating the windows positions. That combined with other options can probably do this. However I think it would make more since to simply use frames instead of new windows to basically perform the same task.

Comment: @neo_codex why do you want to have a window pop up instead of a frame that is used in the main window? The frame would always be "on top" until you change it and it will move with the window.

Comment: I want to be able to have more information show up on the screen without taking too much space, I was also planning on having the window minimize when I don't need it, but it's looking like I won't be able to do that. I was thinking of something very similar to a drop down menu, but instead of a menu, I can put any piece of information I want.

Comment: I really think what you want is a frame that toggles on and off. It would be much less complicated than trying to do this with a window.

Comment: @MarkRansom I just threw together a working concept. Check my 2nd example and let me know what you think. Would you have dome something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so with a little bit of googling I came across this post: [tkinter-detecting-a-window-drag-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45183914/tkinter-detecting-a-window-drag-event)

In that post they show how you can keep track of when the window has moved.
By taking that code and making some small changes we can use the `dragging()` and `stop_drag()` functions to move the top level window back to where it was set to relative to the main window.

That said this will only work in this case. You will need to write something more dynamic to track any new windows you want so they are placed properly and on top of that you will probably want to build this in a `class` so you do not have to manage global variables.

With a combination of this tracking function and using `lift()` to bring the window up we get closer to what you are asking to do.

That said you will probably want remove the tool bar at the top of the root window to be more clean. I would also focus on using a dictionary or list to keep track of open and closed windows and their locations to make the dynamic part of this easier.

```
import tkinter as tk


win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("500x500+0+0")
win2 = None
drag_id = ''


def dragging(event):
    global drag_id
    if event.widget is win:
        if drag_id == '':
            print('start drag')
        else:
            win.after_cancel(drag_id)
            print('dragging')
        drag_id = win.after(100, stop_drag)
        if win2 is not None:
            win2.lift()
            win2.geometry(f"+{win.winfo_x()}+{win.winfo_y() + 30}")


def stop_drag():
    global drag_id, win2, win
    print('stop drag')
    drag_id = ''
    if win2 is not None:
        win2.lift()
        win2.geometry(f"+{win.winfo_x()}+{win.winfo_y() + 30}")



win.bind('<Configure>', dragging)


def button_function():
    global win2
    win2 = tk.Toplevel()
    label = tk.Label(win2, text='drop down', width=7)
    label.pack()
    win2.geometry(f"+{win.winfo_x()}+{win.winfo_y()+30}")


tk.Button(win, command=button_function, width=12).pack()

win.mainloop()
```

EDIT:

Ok so I took some time to write this up in a `class` so you could see how it could be done. I have also added some level of dynamic building of the buttons and pop up windows.

We use a combination of lists and lambdas to perform a little bit of tracking and in the end we pull off exactly what you were asking for.
let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('500x500')
        self.pop_up_list = []
        self.drag_id = ''
        self.button_notes = ['Some notes for new window', 'some other notes for new window', 'bacon that is all!']
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.dragging)
        for ndex, value in enumerate(self.button_notes):
            print(ndex)
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=f'Button {ndex+1}')
            btn.config(command=lambda b=btn, i=ndex: self.toggle_button_pop_ups(i, b))
            btn.grid(row=ndex, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
            self.pop_up_list.append([value, 0, None, btn])

    def dragging(self, event):
        if event.widget is self:
            if self.drag_id == '':
                pass
            else:
                self.after_cancel(self.drag_id)
            self.drag_id = self.after(100, self.stop_drag)
            for p in self.pop_up_list:
                if p[1] == 1:
                    p[2].lift()
                    p[2].geometry(f"+{p[3].winfo_rootx() + 65}+{p[3].winfo_rooty()}")

    def stop_drag(self):
        self.drag_id = ''
        for p in self.pop_up_list:
            if p[1] == 1:
                p[2].lift()
                p[2].geometry(f"+{p[3].winfo_rootx() + 65}+{p[3].winfo_rooty()}")

    def toggle_button_pop_ups(self, ndex, btn):
        p = self.pop_up_list
        if p[ndex][1] == 0:
            p[ndex][1] = 1
            p[ndex][2] = tk.Toplevel(self)
            p[ndex][2].overrideredirect(1)
            tk.Label(p[ndex][2], text=self.pop_up_list[ndex][0]).pack()
            p[ndex][2].geometry(f"+{btn.winfo_rootx() + 65}+{btn.winfo_rooty()}")
        else:
            p[ndex][1] = 0
            p[ndex][2].destroy()
            p[ndex][2] = None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().mainloop()
```

Comment: This is amazing, now I just have to implement this into my code.

Comment: I got it to work and even managed to add a treeview, but I was wondering why when I drag the window with the other windows attached, it keeps minimizing every other application window on my computer.

Comment: That is a windows feature. When you grab a window and drag it back and forth windows will minimize all other windows. Its not something you commonly see because normally when you move a window you simply move it one direction not back and forth.

Comment: oh I see, I guess it just happened because I was trying to test if the windows would stick together, thank you so much

Comment: I managed to add tree views into the code, but now I want to dynamically reshape those tree views when the main window gets reshaped, but I have no idea how to change p[ndex][2] so that the different top level windows get reshaped with .geometry(). I tried creating a function that gets activated in the     def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() section with the line : self.bind("<Configure>", self.resize) and the function is def resize(self, e):
    p = self.pop_up_list
    print("height", e.height, "width", e.width)
    p[0][2].geometry("100x100")

Comment: @neo_codex That is a new question that needs a new post.

Comment: ok well thanks for all the help